# How to understand probability density function?

Tags: statistics, education

I have a probability density function like this:

p(x) = $\begin{cases}1,&0\le x\le1 \\0,& \text{otherwise}   \end{cases}$

I want to know how to understand this PDF. Does this mean the probability of any value x $\in$ [0,1] is p(x)? I guess it's not. Then, if I want to know the probability that x=0.5, is P(0.5)=1 right? If it's right, $\int$p(x)dx=1 could be failed. So how to understand the PDF please?

Comment: If $X$ has PDF $p$ then $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$ while $P(x\leqslant X\leqslant y)=y-x$ for every $0\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant1$.

Comment: This is a continuous distribution. Here, you don't look at the probability at a point because it's just 0. Instead, you look at the probability of a particular interval, which can be calculated as @Did has pointed out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PDF gives you the relative probability of one value over another. In your example, we see that if $0 \le x_1 \le 1$ and $0 \le x_2 \le 1$, then $p(x_1)=1$ and $p(x_2)=1$, so the probabilities will be equal. Your PDF represents a uniform random variable over $[0,1]$. If you had something like this:

$$p(x) = \begin{cases}1,&0\le x\le\frac{1}{2} \\2,&\frac{1}{2}<x\le1\\0,& \text{otherwise}   \end{cases}$$

Then you would say that the probability of $P(X=1)$ is twice the probability of $P(X=0)$. The PDF does not say anything about the actual probabilities.

Comment: "Then you would say that the probability of $P(X=1)$ is twice the probability of $P(X=0)$. The PDF does not say anything about the actual probabilities." I am not following: you would say etc. because $2\times0=0$?

Comment: So when you have a continuous PDF, technically $P(X=x)$ is always 0 (for a single value). To use PDFs effectively, we usually find probabilities of ranges. For example, in the second PDF, we know $P(0\le x\le1)=1$, since probabilities must add to 1. So it would be more useful to ask what is $P(\frac{1}{2}\le x\le1)$? Here, we can say $P(\frac{1}{2}\le x\le1)=2*P(0\le x\le\frac{1}{2})$ (note that the lengths are the same - from 0 to $\frac{1}{2}$ and from $\frac{1}{2}$ to 1). Since probabilities add to 1, we see that $P(0\le x\le\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{3}$ and $P(\frac{1}{2}\le x\le1)=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: ...Which does not concern P(X=0) and P(X=1), hence why even mentioning these?

Comment: He asked about how to interpret PDFs, so I wanted to emphasize that PDFs only show relative probabilities, not actual probabilities. It probably would have been better to use nonzero probabilities though.

Comment: PDFs very much show actual probabilities.